# Is it possible to prove this version of recursion theorem from the simpler one?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recurrence-relations, recursion

The simpler version:

> Let $A$ be a set, $a\in A$, and $f \colon A\to A$ a mapping. Then there exists a unique mapping $g \colon \Bbb N\to A$ such that
>
> 1. $g(0)=a$
>
> 2. $g(n+1)=f(g(n))$

The version I want to prove:

> Let $A$ be a set, $a\in A$, and $f\colon A\times\Bbb N \to A$ a mapping. Then there exists a unique mapping $g \colon \Bbb N\to A$ such that
>
> 1. $g(0)=a$
>
> 2. $g(n+1)=f(g(n),n)$

I would like to ask whether it is possible to apply the first version to prove the second one.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: what is ment by $(n+1)\in \text{dom }g$ ? Isn´t $\text{dom }g\subset A$? and why should $f(g(n),n)$ be undefined?

Comment: @PeterMelech $g$ can be a finite sequence, you can have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402266/prove-the-recursion-theorem.

Comment: Ok, then You shouldn´t write $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow A$ since this would imply $\text{dom }g=\mathbb{N}$ and $g$ is an infinite ( possibly eventually stationary) sequence in this case.

Comment: Many thanks @PeterMelech, I have edited my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can replace $A$ by $A \times \mathbb{N}$ and $a$ by $(a,0)$. Then we define
$$
\hat{f}:\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
A \times \mathbb{N} &\to &A \times \mathbb{N}, \\ (b,n)&\mapsto&\big(f(b,n),n+1\big).
\end{array}\right.
$$
By your first version, we obtain a $g : \mathbb{N} \to A \times \mathbb{N}$ (we will write $g(n) = (g_1(n),g_2(n))$) which satisfies $g(0) = (a,0)$ and 
\begin{align} 
g(n+1) = \hat{f}(g(n)) = \big(f(g(n)),n+1\big)
\end{align}
we can split this equation in two equation (one equation for each component)
\begin{align}
g_1(n+1) &= f(g_1(n),g_2(n)) %\tag{1}
\\
g_2(n+1) &= n+1 %\tag{2}
%\big(g_1(n+1),g_2(n+1)\big) = \big(f(g_1(n),g_2(n)),n+1\big)
\end{align}
Hence, we can see that $g_2(n) = n$, which gives us
\begin{align}
g_1(n+1) &= f(g_1(n),n)
\end{align}
So $g_1$ is the desired function.

Comment: I was editing my A as yours appeared. I make a lot of typos and almost always have to edit.

Comment: Your proof is clear and concise. Many thanks!  <p>I would like to ask is there any intuition to create</p> $\hat{f}:\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
A \times \mathbb{N} &\to &A \times \mathbb{N}, \\ (b,n)&\mapsto&\big(f(b,n),n+1\big).
\end{array}\right.$?

Comment: yes, I wanted to add a second component to my function $g$ which I can easily predict. In this case i added $g_2(n) = n$. This is a justification for the $n+1$ part. Needless to mention that I have to use the function $f$ somewhere and I need a function which maps into $A\times\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A^*=A\times \Bbb N.$ For $(b,n)\in A^*$  let $f^*(b,n)=(f(b,n),n+1).$

By version 1, for any $a\in A$ there exists a unique $g^*:\Bbb N\to A^*$ such that $g^*(0)=(a,0)$ and $g^*(n+1)=f^*(g^*(n))$  for all $n\in \Bbb N.$

Let $p_1:A^*\to A$ be the projection to the first co-ordinate (i.e. $p_1(b,n)=b$).

Let $g(0)=a$ and let $g(n+1)=p_1(g^*(n+1)).$

Comment: it seems like we had the same idea but I realized that your proof doesn't explain why $g(n+1) = f(g(n),n)$ is true.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek . I left that for the proposer to finish.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, don't you mean $f^*(b,n)=(f(b,n),n+1)$ rather than $f^*(b,n)=(f(b,n),n)$?

Comment: @leanhdung . Right! I have fixed it. In fact I first wrote $n+1$ and changed it to $n$ before posting.